How to create tables in Supabase automatically?
I am currently experimenting with programming a Flutter app to keep track of school grades. I'm trying to create a new table in Supabase whenever a new user registers. The table will store their data. The trigger works, but unfortunately, I can't get the function to do what it's supposed to do.
My trigger looks like this:
create trigger create_database_for_new_user
after insert on auth.users for each row
execute function create_database_for_new_user ();

This is my function:
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        new_table_name TEXT; 
    BEGIN
        
        new_table_name := 'user_' || NEW.id;

       
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
            id bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
            inserted_at timestamp with time zone default timezone(''utc''::text, now()) not null,
            updated_at timestamp with time zone default timezone(''utc''::text, now()) not null,
            date timestamp with time zone not null,      
            grade numeric not null,                    
            type text not null                       
        );', new_table_name);

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
END;

It would be great if that works, because that way i am able to save all the grades in one table for each user. Solving it this way is probably a bit more complicated, but the project is generally not designed for many users. Since I will be working more with Supabase in the future, I would be really interested in how this function can be implemented. I’m not very familiar with SQL yet, thank you in advance for your help!

Slightly off topic: this is the wrong data model. A user should be a record or an identifier pointing to this record, but no user should have its own tables. Check the 3NF data model

Yes, that might be, but ist there any way to solve the Problem?

Did you try this?
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_database_for_new_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    new_table_name TEXT;
BEGIN
    -- Generate the table name based on the user's ID
    new_table_name := 'user_' || NEW.id;

    -- Create the table dynamically for the new user
    EXECUTE format('
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
            id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
            inserted_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT timezone(''utc''::text, now()) NOT NULL,
            updated_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT timezone(''utc''::text, now()) NOT NULL,
            date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
            grade NUMERIC NOT NULL,
            type TEXT NOT NULL
        );', new_table_name);

    -- Return the new row after the table creation
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Thanks for the corrected version! It works as expected. The dynamic table creation based on the user ID is exactly what I needed.
